# GCD - TCL, error = cant use non-numeric string as operand as of &

Tags: tcl, greatest-common-divisor

im trying to write a gcd (Stein's algorithm) in TCl and i'm using '&' as a bitwise operand so i can check if the number is odd or even, by multiplying the number (bitwise) by 1 (result 0 is even, 1 is odd) when i run the code in linux using genus, it keeps giving me the error :

'can't use non-numeric strin as operand of '&' '

im very new to TCL, does anybody can help how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

i looked for an answer but i didnt really find...

Comment: You need to show us the code that gives the error.

Comment: while {($a & 1) == 0 && ($b & 1) == 0} {
        set new_a [expr {$a / 2}]
        set new_b [expr {$b / 2}]
        return [expr {2  * [gcd  $new_a $new_b]}]

Answer (score 0):

Please give the exact code which is causing your problem.

You're probably expressing a binary number incorrectly.

Here are some examples which show that expression a binary 1 as "b1" is not allowed because it should be "0b1", or just 1!

```
tcl8.6.8> expr {65 & 1}
1

tcl8.6.8> expr {64 & 1}
0

tcl8.6.8> expr {65 & "b1"}
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&"

tcl8.6.8> expr {65 & "0b1"}
1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, actually it was solved by just reorgnazing the if statements again but nothing else

Comment: Please edit your original question to show what the original code was.    Without seeing what the problem was, then nobody else will be able to learn from visiting this Q&A.